# Can you create duplicate character names in Planetside 2?

Tags: planetside-2

I know I cant switch faction, so am I able to just create a new character with the same username? Or do I have to delete my original?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**
Every single character of any user of any faction on any server has a unique name.
Although first-hand evidence is hard to come by in the form of a FAQ topic or something similar, there are enough leads:

- It can be inferred from randomly found screenshots of character screens;

  [image: Randomly found screenshot #3749 - no affiliation]
- Or from visiting fora threads like [this one](https://forums.daybreakgames.com/ps2/index.php?threads/cant-use-single-name-for-multiple-characters.48677/).

This has probably played a major role in how in Planetside 2 "[every](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218230/discussions/0/523897277918126402) [username](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218230/discussions/0/618463738391785589/) [is](https://forums.daybreakgames.com/ps2/index.php?threads/name-unavailable.90360/) [already](https://apps.quanticfoundry.com/characternames/) [taken](https://www.neogaf.com/threads/sorry-that-name-is-already-taken.488656/)".

Advice: **change the capitalization of one of the characters**, since it will register as a unique username (unless taken, of course).

Comment: Am I able to delete a former account so I can use its name again?

Comment: @THECAKEISTALKING yes, you are, but you might have to wait a while before it gets registered (I've read it can take up to 24 hours), and the name *could* be claimed in the meantime (the risk partially depending on its uniqueness).